# exported component from feature module not loaded in route

Tags: angular

My `appModule` imports a feature-module named `SudokuModule`. `SudokuModule` has a component `SudokuComponent` in its exports array. In `app.component.html` I can use `app-sudoku`. So this part works.

However when I set up a route to a `SharedSudokuComponent` I can not load `app-sudoku` in `shared-sudoku.component.html`. So that specific route is apparently not properly importing the `SudokuComponent`. Any idea where I went wrong on this?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SudokuModule } from './components/sudoku/sudoku.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    SudokuModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**sudoku.module.ts (feature module)**

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FontAwesomeModule } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import { SudokuCellComponent } from "./sudoku-cell/sudoku-cell.component";
import { SudokuOverlayComponent } from "./sudoku-overlay/sudoku-overlay.component";
import { SnackbarComponent } from "./sudoku-snackbar/snackbar.component";
import { SudokuComponent } from "./sudoku.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SudokuComponent,
    SudokuCellComponent,
    SudokuOverlayComponent,
    SnackbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SudokuComponent
  ]
})
export class SudokuModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedSudokuComponent } from './components/shared-sudoku/shared-sudoku.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sudoku/shared', component: SharedSudokuComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
  })
],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: This way is very hard to understand. Can you provide http://plnkr.co or https://stackblitz.com

Comment: I think that you must declare your SharedSudokuComponent in the root module to be used, and then use app-sudoku selector in the html of SharedSudokuComponent.